# Finding if selected cell is within range

Tags: delphi

So i have a StringGrid and i want to find out for example if the currently selected cell is within 1,1 and 2,2 if so change the value i to 1. is this possible?
I also want to know if it is possible to do it for single cells. So lets say if the selected cell is 0,0 it will do a showmessage('error'); this will all be activated by a buttonclick.

Comment: Er, grid computing is something else altogether!

Comment: The same you should do also with your [`previously created account`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1565179/matt-biggs). Anyway, I think you can contact administrators to merge your accounts into one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In the following example, the `IsCellInRange` function returns True, if the cell specified by coordinates using the [`TGridCoord`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TGridCoord) data type lies in the range specified by [`TGridRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TGridRect) data type, False if doesn't:

```
uses
  Math;

function IsCellInRange(const Cell: TGridCoord; const Range: TGridRect): Boolean;
begin
  Result := InRange(Cell.X, Range.Left, Range.Right) and
    InRange(Cell.Y, Range.Top, Range.Bottom);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Cell: TGridCoord;
  Range: TGridRect;
begin
  Cell.X := StringGrid1.Col;
  Cell.Y := StringGrid1.Row;
  Range.Left := 1;
  Range.Top := 1;
  Range.Right := 2;
  Range.Bottom := 2;

  if IsCellInRange(Cell, Range) then
    StringGrid1.Cells[Cell.X, Cell.Y] := '1'
  else
    ShowMessage('Error, cell is not in range!');
end;
```

Comment: Quite over-complicated isn't it ? P.S. I know I could use nested procedure for `IsCellInRange` (just assuming it can be used somewhere else).

Comment: `TGridRect` is crying out for some nice helper methods

Comment: Wouldn't you be better with `InRange(Cell.X, Range.Left, Range.Right) and InRange(Cell.Y, Range.Top, Range.Bottom)`?

Comment: @David, yeah that will be stylish. Thanks for the tip!